# How to add Parameter level conditions in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

so I'm trying to create a conditional parameter for ConfigRule Resources created via AWS Cloudformation. However, I'm having problems on how should I properly code it. I tried all sorts of things and followed the docs [1] [2] mentioned. Below is the simplest code I could think but its still not working, hence the error "Yaml not well-formed"

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/conditionally-launch-aws-cloudformation-resources-based-on-user-input/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if

```
            Conditions:
              IsAllResources: !Equals 
              - !Ref IncludeAllResources 
              - 'True'

            Resources:
              AWSConfigRule:
                Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
                Properties:
                  ConfigRuleName: RequiredTags
                  Description: Checks whether your resources have the specified tags.
                  InputParameters:
                    tag1Key: ProjectCode
                    tag1Value: !Ref ProjectCode
                    tag2Key: SupportContact
                    tag2Value: !Ref SupportContact
                  Source:
                    Owner: AWS
                    SourceIdentifier: REQUIRED_TAGS
                  Scope:
                    ComplianceResourceTypes:
                      - AWS::EC2::Volume
                      - AWS::EC2::Instance
                      - AWS::Redshift::Cluster
                      - AWS::Redshift::ClusterSnapshot
                      - AWS::RDS::DBInstance
                      - AWS::RDS::DBSnapshot
                      - AWS::S3::Bucket
                      - AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
                      - AWS::CodeBuild::Project
                      - AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
                      - AWS::DynamoDB::Table
                    !If 
                      - IsAllResources
                        - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
                        - AWS::Lambda::Function
                      - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Appreciate your inputs on this. Thank you.

Added updates:
Fixed the issue using this:
Not sure if CFN supports more complex coding

```
                    Scope:
                      ComplianceResourceTypes:    
                        !If 
                        - IsAllResources
                        -
                          - AWS::EC2::Volume
                          - AWS::EC2::Instance
                        - 
                          - AWS::EC2::Volume
```

Comment: I think have to do it individually. One row `- !If [IsAllResources, AWS::CloudFormation::Stack, Ref "AWS::NoValue"]`. Second row `- !If [IsAllResources, AWS::Lambda::Function, Ref "AWS::NoValue"]`. Difficult to format code in comments.

Comment: If you have trouble formatting YAML manually, consider using tools that generate it for you, like AWS CDK. It's hard to tell without putting it into console, but maybe `!If` should be an element of list itself, `- !If `

Comment: indent your !If block a couple times so it's right under AWS - I was able to at least validate the template successfully after that.

Comment: ComplianceResourceTypes:    
                            !If 
                            - IsAllResources
                            -
                              - AWS::EC2::Volume
                              - AWS::EC2::Instance
                            - 
                              - AWS::EC2::Volume
I fixed it like this, not sure if CFN supports a complex coding than this (as what I was trying before didn't work)